# how to empty the object list for pear.php to ensure that destructors are not called more than once

Tags: php, pear, owncloud

trying to get owncloud encryption to work whit xampp but geting Fatal error:

> Cannot redeclare _PEAR_call_destructors() (previously declared in
>   C:\xampp\php\pear\PEAR.php:735) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\owncloud\3rdparty\PEAR.php on line 777. and in
>   pear.php line 762 it stands 
>   // Empty the object list to ensure that destructors are not called more than once.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a problem of your php setup (which php version do you use for example)? And are you using the latest version of the encryption app? It's quite unlikely that such an error would go unnoticed if it would occur on common setups, which XAMPP qualifies as, I would say. If you're sure that everything's correct on your end, and that you meet all minimum requirements, you could always report a bug here: https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues

Comment: this is not a problem whit php, its because pear.php is loaded from 2 locations